# How to extract from a folder into an Excel, image names?

Tags: excel, vba

I really need help in creating a vba because I have no idea about vba.
I have downloaded images in a folder into my desktop, and every image has a code as title.
I need to extract that code into an Excel.
I give you an example of an image title: 010117
That is how appears the title of my images, of course are different numbers (for ej 011225, 191143, etc).

Could you tell me the code I need to write in VBA so, I can extract those codes into an Excel?
Thank you!

Comment: If I understand your question, you need to make a list in excel of filenames?

Comment: If you dont know VBA you can try use cmd. enter into folder with images and use command DIR /B, then copy result from cmd into excel.

Answer (score 2):

From [ExtendOffice.com](http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/627-excel-list-files.html#a2), this will get the list of file names:

```
Option Explicit
Sub GetFileNames()
Dim xRow As Long
Dim xDirect$, xFname$, InitialFoldr$
InitialFoldr$ = "C:\" '<<< Startup folder to begin searching from
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
  .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\"
  .Title = "Please select a folder to list Files from"
  .InitialFileName = InitialFoldr$
  .Show
  If .SelectedItems.Count <> 0 Then
    xDirect$ = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    xFname$ = Dir(xDirect$, 7)
    Do While xFname$ <> ""
      ActiveCell.Offset(xRow) = xFname$
      xRow = xRow + 1
      xFname$ = Dir
    Loop
  End If
End With
End Sub
```

And from [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21069398/vba-find-and-replace-part-of-file-path/), this will strip the file suffixes:

```
With Columns("A:A")
    .Replace What:= _
      ".*", _
      Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
      MatchCase:= False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
End With
```